# A Tense Question ;) Pun intended

Tags: tenses, syntactic-analysis

> 1. Medical professionals are worried that too many general practitioners are overprescribing them, **which will cause** bacteria to build up a resistance.

Or

> 2. Medical professionals are worried that too many general practitioners are overprescribing them, **which causes** bacteria to build up a resistance.

a. Which sentence is more grammatically correct in terms of verb / tense consistency?
b. Is Sentence 2 better at conveying the same point?

Comment: The preceding sentence references antibiotics. So we can assume "them" refers to that. Any thoughts about the actual question  I asked?

Comment: @KJO My apologies, this was my first post ever. Is it outside the boundary to ask a question relating to tense consistency? It's not proofreading, is it?

Comment: In the "tour" on this site it says avoid "Proofreading ("are there any mistakes?"), unless the source of concern is clearly specified" Since I clearly specified "tense consistency" doesn't that qualify as a legitimate question? BTW - thanks for the warm welcome.

Comment: I'd go with *which **allows*** bacteria...

Comment: Any answer here would be subjective. Both are fine.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between your two sentences is "causes" versus "will cause." To answer your question of which is more correct, the second is more correct and "may cause," which accounts for uncertainty, would be even more correct.

That said, your sentences are unclear for two reasons.

1. The object of the pronoun "them" is unclear. While presumably it's "antibiotics," it sounds here like the object is "medical professionals."
2. Are not general practitioners a type of medical professionals?

Also, "are worried" is passive voice and therefore sounds weak.

I would rephrase this as, "Experts worry that doctors are over-prescribing antibiotics, and that this may lead to drug-resistant strains of bacteria."

Comment: The first part of this answer is debatable; in terms of grammar, both versions given in the question are equally correct. The only difference is _semantic_: one construction may express the actual situation better than the other. But the reason for my downvote is the statement, “Also, ‘are worried’ is passive voice and therefore sounds weak”. Not only is it patently untrue that passive constructions ‘sound weak’, but _are worried_ is not a passive construction to begin with. I do agree that your rewrite is better than the original sentence, though (except _medical professionals_ ≠ _experts_).

Comment: There is no such thing as *more* or *less* correct. Something is either grammatical or it isn't. Anything else that is a matter of style or preference, and can only be looked at objectively through common usage. Otherwise it's subjective.